# (iOS) Obj-c .cer store from string to SecCertificateRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

I have tried several things online and read about this for hours and went through about 20 walkthroughs. All of them are doing it differently and don't point to what I am doing.

I have my .cer as a string, returned via api. Then I want to pass this to a `SecCertificateRef` object in Obj-c. I am getting a bridge cast error, I tried the. `(__bridge id)certificate` and `(__bridge CFStringRef)certificate`. No dice. Still errors around cast type.

I am still learning Obj-c and specifically around the certificate handling. I have a certificate as a string `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF4zCCA8...` and I want to store it in the key chain and then use it when making network calls. Surprisingly, I could not find any help walkthroughs or guides for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like no one came to the rescue, so I figured this out. More simple than I thought. It complains of a deprecated method with `initWithBase64Encoding`, but trying to use the new method from Foundation caused issues.

```
    NSString * s = @"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- ....." // My Certificate raw string.

    NSRange r1 = [s rangeOfString:@"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"];
    NSRange r2 = [s rangeOfString:@"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"];
    NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
    NSString *subCert = [s substringWithRange:rSub];

    NSData *rawCertificate = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:subCert];
    SecCertificateRef parsedCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)rawCertificate);

    // This gave me a valid certificate I could store.
```